# Is there a way to place a default image for control in edit/view mode?

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I am developing a custom control containing a set of icons that present different status of a device.
It works after binding datacontext.

This is the XAML.
[image]

This is what it is in EDIT mode after it is dragged to a Window.

[image]

So, as you can see here ,it's totally blind.

Is there possible to place a fake image as a replacement while it is in edit mode?

How?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add design instance dataContext. use the d:DataContext attribute to set the data context to some static reference of your actual class and you will get design time data

here is a good walkthrough:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602274(v=vs.95).aspx